# Test Application C#; Failed

Tags: c#, error-handling, patch

Hey does anyone know why my script keeps crashing on my VS 2019 code editor? Everything is fine with my code as it seems to me but the compiler just starts and then ends in a snap and I need someone to help me patch things up.

Here is the code:

```
namespace Test
{
    class ovoviviparous //<--Base Class Defined--

    {

        public string type = "Aquatic"; //<-- Animal field --

        public void Fish() //<-- Animal Method --

        {

            Console.WriteLine("Bubbles");

        }



    }

    class SeaofNihon : ovoviviparous //<-- creating constructor (child class derived) --

    {

        public string marineCreaturetype = "Manta Birotis"; //<-- Genus Field --

    }

    class program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            SeaofNihon myFish = new SeaofNihon(); //<-- Creating myFish object --

            myFish.Fish(); //<-- calling Bubbles() method from base class on myFish object 

            Console.WriteLine(myFish.type + " " + myFish.marineCreaturetype); //<-- Displaying values from the type and MarineCreaturetype field.

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: soo _what error_ are you getting? (or do you just mean that your _console window_ is closing once the program is _done_, because you don't have, for example, a `Console.ReadKey()` at the end to wait for user interaction before the program is done?)

Answer (score -1):

you may add "Console.Readline()" under the code "Console.WriteLine()" to let your compiler show your outputs

Comment: Console.Readline() method is used to force user input in a console app, it has nothing the compiler to show the output.